# MATLAB Simulink scope with text in X axis

Tags: matlab, graph

I need to make graphs, where X axis is a date and Y is a value. All calculations are made using Simulink. The problem is that scopes display default Simulink time in their X axis. Is there anything I can change, to make described graphs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use plot function to get the desired graph with day of the month on the x-axis. The Graph can be for a particular month. 
Example: 
For the Month of May and dates 1st, 7th, 14th and 28th-

```
x=[1 7 14 28];
>> y=[2 10 3 1];
>> plot(x,y)
```

However, you need to make sure you import the data into 'y' variable correctly (from simulation output variable) so that it corresponds to your x-axis date-wise data.